# remote connection to mysql failing

Tags: mysql, linode, ubuntu-13.04

Whenever I try to connect to my mysql database remotely I am receiving

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111
```

as a response,

Currently my bind address is:

```
#bind-address           = 173.230.131.33
```

commented because:

```
bind-address            = 173.230.131.33
```

will not allow mysql to start.

I also tried

```
bind-address             = 0.0.0.0
```

without success

My iptables show as

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 639 packets, 48107 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
1380K  163M fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 475 packets, 73738 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
1380K  163M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I do not believe I have a problem host (currently hosting with linode), ubuntu 13.04 box.
Mysql and all other services were installed with ISPConfig

I do have a user setup for % host on mysql so it is not a user restriction

SSH tunneling is out of the question unfortunately. Any help is appreciated

Also showing: netstat -ntlp | grep 3306

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11406/mysqld
```

Comment: Aaaand why is ssh tunneling out of the question?

Comment: because it would not be readily and easily possible for the project I have

Comment: So for this project, you're completely fine exposing your MySQL server to the internet (and communicating with it via an insecure, cleartext protocol) but not ok with using what is the industry standard method of providing ad-hoc secure, remote database access?

Comment: SSH works from the Internet...apply the same rule for port 3306. Seems  that eth0 is the wrong interface for incoming traffic to your Mysql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~ nmap -p 3306 173.230.131.33

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-02-04 20:15 CST
Nmap scan report for ftd.fasttrackdispatch.com (173.230.131.33)
Host is up (0.044s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

Looks like your MySQL port is closed.